# Docker でビルドをしようとすると、エラーがでてしまいます

Tags: docker

ビルドしようとして

```
docker build -t jlab:latest /Users/名前/Desktop/MyDocker
```

で実行すると、

```
ERROR [2/8] RUN opt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo wget vim cu  0.2s
```

と表示されてしまい、すすめずにいます。
経験者様に助けていただきたいです…

#### Docker file の内容

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN opt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo wget vim curl gawk make gcc

RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sh Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh -b  && \
    rm -f Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -  && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV PATH $PATH:/root/anaconda3/bin

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pandas_datareader
RUN pip install mplfinance

RUN wget --quiet http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz -0 ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
    cd ta-lib/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
    make && \
    sudo make install && \
    cd .. && \
    pip install TA-Lib && \
    rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /workspace

CMD ["jupyter-lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0","--port=8888" ,"--no-browser", "--allow-root", "--LabApp.token=''"]
```

Comment: Dockerfile の内容も質問中に追記してみて下さい。少なくとも`opt-get`はタイプミスで正しくは`apt-get`なはずです。

Comment: cubick♦様　親切なコメント、ありがとうございます。　目視で確かめてもみましたが、コピー＆ペーストした為、optと表示されていると思われます。　アドバイスありがとうございます。fileの内容も追記させていただきました。

Comment: コピペと言うことはなにか書籍やwebサイトを参照して試してる、ということでしょうか？それらの情報元 (URL等) も念のため質問に追記してみてください。